# Using result of awaitMessages outside try discord.js

Tags: node.js, variables, async-await, discord.js

I'm using awaitMessages to get message responses to a prompt.
Here is my current code

```js
// other code... all fine
try {
  const response = await message.channel.awaitMessages(
    message2 => message2.content > 0 && message2.content < 11,
    {
      max: 1,
      time: 20000,
      errors: ['time'],
    },
  );
}
catch (err) {
  console.log(err);
  return message.channel.send('No value given, or value was invalid.');
}
const reply = parseInt(response.first().content);
// gives error right there ^^^
```

It gives the error

```
ReferenceError: response is not defined
```

If I add a line to define `response` as `null` it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define `response` outside the try-catch scope:

```
let response;
try {
    response = await message.channel.awaitMessages(
            message2 => message2.content > 0 && message2.content < 11, {
            max: 1,
            time: 20000,
            errors: ['time']
        });
} catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return message.channel.send('No value given, or value was invalid.');
}
const reply = parseInt(response.first().content);
```

Comment: ahh, I defined it differently when I tried it and used `let response = null` then `let response = ...`